# How to get Value from Query

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter-2

Please check my script first.

```
    $arealeader = $this->db->query("select OutletCode from arealeader where NipLeader = '$Nip'")->result();
            $Mp=array();
            foreach($arealeader as $row)
            {
                $Mp[] = $this->db->query("select Nip from Employee where OutletCode = '".$row->OutletCode."'")->result();
                $MpCount[] =  $this->db->query("select Nip from Employee where OutletCode = '".$row->OutletCode."'")->num_rows();

            }   

           echo array_sum($MpCount) // Result 18 
            foreach($Mp as $row)
            {
                echo $row->Nip."<br>";
            }
```

How my Script work: in `$Arealeader` i select every OutletCode from my table with condition. Then after i have the OutletCode, i want to select `Nip` From employee with `OutletCode` as Condition.

Problem : When `echo $row->Nip."<br>";` . I only get white screen.

```
    var_dump($row);`

    i get this 
`array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#52 (1) {
        ["Nip"]=>
        string(9) "201603172"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to called var_dump on $row?

Comment: You should join those queries so it is only 1 query. That can save you a lot of performance.

Comment: Instead of var_dump for row, try to vardump $Mp, after the first foreach.

Comment: from `var_dump($Mp)` every Nip that match with the condtion are showed Up

Comment: @Boby `print_r($row);` post the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ivar : You should join those queries so it is only 1 query. That can save you a lot of performance`

I change my script above and change into this.

```
$data['master'] = $this->db->query("select a.*,b.fullname from SaldoCuti a 
                  left join employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip
                  left join outlet c on b.OutletCode = c.OutletCode
                  left join arealeader d on c.OutletCode = d.OutletCode     
                  where NipLeader = '$Nip'")->result();
```

I found it works fine for me now. If you guys has better way, please tell me.